# How to handle multiple objects in android returned by Azure Mobile Services Custom Api

Tags: android, json, azure, azure-mobile-services

Sorry if not well documented, but this is my first question here. I am using Azure Mobile Services with javascript backend, and creating an android app.

I then created a Custom Api that executes a stored procedure with some input parameters I send.

The webservice is being called and responding accordingly, as I can see the log with the JSON output on Azure portal, in this case returning an array with two objects:

```
   [ { peoplename: 'Andre Felipe', __createdat: { Sat, 11 Jul 2015 12:03:33 GMT nanosecondsDelta: 0 }, cellid: 3, date: '12/08/2015', allstages: 'true', devotion: 'true', messageoftheweek: 'true', nofvisitors: 10, nofmembers: 3 }, { peoplename: 'Andre Felipe', __createdat: { Sat, 11 Jul 2015 11:36:52 GMT nanosecondsDelta: 0 }, cellid: 3, date: '11/08/2015', allstages: 'false', devotion: 'false', messageoftheweek: 'true', nofvisitors: 2, nofmembers: 2 }]
```

I created a class called reportsbydateandleader that has all this properties, peoplename, cellid, allstages, and so on..

When the API is called like the code below, it correctly deserializes ONLY the first object, which makes sense to me:

```
    ListenableFuture<reportsbydateandleader> result = global.mClient.invokeApi( "reportsbydateandleader","POST",queryParams,reportsbydateandleader.class)
```

The question is I don't know how to handle the output to deserialize multiple objects. Any ideas?

Comment: hey did you find the answer ???? ...if yes..then plzz share

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post, which explicitly shows how to deserialize an array: http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/04/android-how-to-deserialize-both-xml-and-json/

One thing to be aware of is how your backend handles a single item.  Javascript notably can have the same variable hold both arrays and objects at various parts of the lifecycle, so you may, for example, be seeing an array for 2+ returned values but then an object for 1 returned value.  I'm not saying that is occuring, but you need to be aware - use Postman to verify that your API is returning the right thing in both cases (i.e. it always returns an array).